# What would be a good way to evaluate algebraic expressions in Visual Basic.NET?

Tags: vb.net, parsing, math, expression-trees

I am looking for a way to simplify algebraic expressions in VB.NET. It is preferred if you can give me a link to a pre-written library or class, but pointers on how to write one are also appreciated.

Comment: You should specify some examples, even if in pseudo-code. This question is vague as is. Example: do you find x = Math.Pow(3,2) a simplified version of x = 3 ^ 2? The other way around? or x = (3^2) versus x = 9? etc.

Comment: What kind of algebraic expressions do you want to simplify? Wikipedia redirects "Algebraic expressions" to "[Expressions (mathematics)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_(mathematics))", where it is defined as "a finite combination of symbols that are well-formed according to the rules applicable in the context at hand". Without knowing what kind of expressions you need to simplify (simple sums? Integrals? Polynomial fractions? The possibilities are endless...) it is impossible to tell you where to start. Except that Matlab can already do this for you...

Comment: I mean expressions like: 5x - 3x + 4 * (3 - 2). I want a (relatively) simple one, with support for: 1 variable, +, -, *, / and parenthesis.

Comment: do you want to simplify this to 2 * x + 4?

Comment: No, I want to simplify it to 2x + 4.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [Wolfram|Alpha API](http://products.wolframalpha.com/api/).

Comment: I don't want to make a request, though.